# Postgresql Logical replication initial slot snapshot too large

Tags: postgresql, replication

I'm trying to replicate some data from one database to another with logical replication.

But it gets stuck into the catchup state. When I'm looking at the logs `initial slot snapshot too large` I'm not sure of the exact meaning?

I'm a bit stuck and not sure where to look at. And what scares me is that if I look at the lag the wal keep increasing.

```
SELECT pid, usename, application_name, state
, pg_current_wal_lsn() AS current_lsn
, sent_lsn
, pg_size_pretty(pg_wal_lsn_diff(pg_current_wal_lsn(), sent_lsn)) AS sent_diff
, write_lsn
, pg_size_pretty(pg_wal_lsn_diff(pg_current_wal_lsn(), write_lsn)) AS write_diff
, replay_lsn
, pg_size_pretty(pg_wal_lsn_diff(pg_current_wal_lsn(), replay_lsn)) AS replay_diff
, write_lag, flush_lag, replay_lag
FROM pg_stat_replication
ORDER BY application_name, pid;
-[ RECORD 1 ]----+----------------
pid              | 23031
usename          | ...
application_name | ...
state            | catchup
current_lsn      | 36/1F6562B0
sent_lsn         | E/14669F88
sent_diff        | 160 GB
write_lsn        | E/4B6E1CA8
write_diff       | 159 GB
replay_lsn       | E/4B6E1CA8
replay_diff      | 159 GB
write_lag        | 
flush_lag        | 
replay_lag       |
```

Comment: Not sure, but after looking at the code, perhaps increasing `max_connections` will help.

Comment: What makes you think that @LaurenzAlbe

Comment: Because the error message is thrown if something exceeds that number.

Comment: I've tried to add table by table, looks like it's working but i'm facing another issue ... https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/262444/could-not-start-wal-streaming-replication-slot-is-active

Answer (score 0):

Snapshots for logical [are the inverse of normal snapshots](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/1c006c067124403d63b6ad3eac687b4217f05691/src/backend/replication/logical/snapbuild.c#L618-L621), in that they store a list of committed xact between xmin/xmax rather than a list of in-flight xact.

The max size of the list is [based on max_connections](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/1c006c067124403d63b6ad3eac687b4217f05691/src/backend/storage/ipc/procarray.c#L2053-L2056).  So as Lorenz says, increasing max_connections might help. But also worth checking for an old or long-running/idle transaction, as the inverted logical rep snapshots can bloat if the global xmin horizon is further back.

And finally, existing slots will also hold back the xmin used for the snapshot. The [`GetOldestSafeDecodingTransactionId()` function](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/1c006c067124403d63b6ad3eac687b4217f05691/src/backend/storage/ipc/procarray.c#L2941) determines the xmin used for building the logical snapshot. What this means is that if you are running a bunch of these concurrently, the ones that start later are more likely to fail. The earliest slot will peg your xmin. Late starts need to build a snapshot that includes every xid committed after the earliest slot. The `xmin` column in the view [`pg_replication_slots`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/view-pg-replication-slots.html) might help determine if this is causing the problem.